# When I send files separated by packets, the new created file is empty

Tags: java

I am making a client-server program, which separates the file into packets. When I send a file, and when I open it it's empty. My problem is that empty file, how can I correct the code, to work. I want to separate the file, and if something happen with one of the packets to send it from another PC. I'm not good at java, but I am trying to improve my skills. Here are the both codes:
**Server part:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PacketServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create socket
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(29311);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");

            Socket sock = servsock.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

            // sendfile
            File myFile = new File("D://test.txt");
            System.out.println(myFile.length());

            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            output.println(myFile.length());

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending...");

            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int obshto = (int) myFile.length();
            int b = obshto / 60;
            int c = obshto % 60;// ako file ne e kraen broi paketi ot 60 byte
            System.out.println(c);
            int packet;
            int gpacket;
            for (packet = 1; packet <= b; packet++) {

                System.out.println("izprashta packet:" + packet
                        + " s golemina " + 60 * packet + " bit / "
                        + myFile.length() + " w moment: " + now);
                os.write(mybytearray, 0, 60);
                if ((c != 0) && (b == packet)) {
                    gpacket = c;
                    System.out.println("izprashta packet:" + packet
                            + " s golemina " + (c) + " bit / "
                            + myFile.length() + " w moment: " + now);
                    os.write(mybytearray, 0, c);
                }
            }
            os.flush();
            sock.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and
**Client part:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class PacketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int filesize = 6022386;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 29311);
        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());

        String response = input.nextLine();
        int Fsize = Integer.parseInt(response);

        // receive file
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D://Receive/test.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        // obshto packets kam momenta
        int obshto = Fsize;
        int b = obshto / 60;
        int c = obshto % 60;
        int bytesRead;
        int current;

        for (b = obshto / 60; b >= 1; b--) {

            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, (b * 60), 60);
            current = bytesRead;
            long now1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            do {
                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
                        (mybytearray.length - current));
                System.out.println("bytesRead " + bytesRead);

                if (bytesRead <= Fsize)
                    current += bytesRead;

                System.out.println("bytesRead " + bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead > -1);
            System.out.println("poluchava packet:" + b + " s golemina" + 60 * b
                    + " bit / " + Fsize + " w moment: " + now1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0, 60);
            if ((c != 0) && (b == 1)) {

                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, c);
                current = bytesRead;
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                do {
                    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
                            (mybytearray.length - current));
                    // System.out.println("bytesRead " + bytesRead);

                    if (bytesRead <= Fsize)
                        current += bytesRead;

                    // System.out.println("bytesRead "+ bytesRead);
                } while (bytesRead > -1);
                System.out.println("poluchava packet:" + (b + 1)
                        + " s golemina" + c + " bit / " + Fsize + " w moment: "
                        + now);

                bos.write(mybytearray, 0, c);
            }

            bos.flush();

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end - start);

            bos.close();
            sock.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This whole packet stuff doesn't make much sense. The underlying TCP/IP stack will send the bytes sent to the stream as it wants grouping your 60 bytes packets together or cutting packets in the middle. Just send everything that needs to be sent, and read everything needed to be read without this packet handling. It doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done? Can you successfully read a file? Can you successfully send any string to the target machine? Can you successfully save any string to a file?

Comment: If I can't separate a file into packets, which are real. what command can I use to view each send/received packet?

Comment: Use a network sniffer like Ethereal: http://www.ethereal.com

Comment: is that program something like Wireshark?

Comment: But I need to separate the file, and if I don't receive ACK, to send the packets again from another PC.

Comment: @ValentinaGenova No you don't. If the data isn't received you will get an exception, and there is no reason to think that sending from another PC will succeed when this one fails. You seem to be trying to reinvent TCP.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to simulate P2P network, that's my aim. And the rules of sending and reciving files is that I've described.If the sending isn't sucsessfull, to send the lost packet again from diff PC.

Answer (score 1):

A common of suggestions

- don't mix text and binary on the same stream unless you really know what you are doing. This will only lead to confusion.
- use existing libraries like apache commons IOUtils if you can or read them and see how they work.
- format your code so its readable.
- your code is far more complicated than it needs to be and it not clear why. What is `60` there for?

Can you make you question clear with a `?` so we know what it is.

Comment: Excuse me, I am trying to monitor packets, which I send/receive with  a file.

Comment: You can't monitor packets in pure java. All you know is when the OS returns something to java. A hint is that the MTU maximum transmission unit is around 1500 bytes and if you ever see more than this, you are seeing coalesced data.

Comment: You will never see dropped packets in TCP, in fact you can never know for sure where one starts and another finishes. Just because you send 60 bytes at a time doesn't mean that is what happens on teh wire.  The OS is likely to determine this is inefficient and combine the writes into packets of up to 1500 bytes. Nagle's algorithm is but one strategy which is used. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm

Comment: So, these times, which I see aren't real, but they have something common with a real times for the packets or not?

Comment: unlikely. If you want to time the packets accurately you need to a) read as much as you can so there a minimum of buffered data, b) use nanoTime as milli-seconds is not accurate enough c) not write anything to the console as this is extremely slow. d) ideally avoid giving up the cpu with any blocking operations by busy waiting and ideally lock the thread to a specific core. e.g. with a thread affinity library I wrote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. You don't have to split the data into packets while it's handled by the transport OSI layer (TCP/IP protocol).

Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create socket
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(13267);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");

            Socket sock = servsock.accept();
            System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

            // Send file
            File myFile = new File("source.pdf");
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            os.flush();
            sock.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int filesize = 6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        // Localhost
        Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 13267);
        System.out.println("Connecting...");

        // Receive file
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
        InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("source-copy.pdf");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        current = bytesRead;

        do {
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
                    (mybytearray.length - current));
            if (bytesRead >= 0)
                current += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > -1);   

        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
        bos.flush();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - start);
        bos.close();
        sock.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to see the behavior of each packet, that's why I separate the file into packets.

Comment: What do you mean "pocket's behavior"?

Comment: When are the packets send/received are they dropped. I want to make trace output file with this information.

Comment: Why do you ignore the result of InputStream.read() when you read a file. It should never be ignored.

Comment: I can't anderstand your idea, I've told that I am newbie in Java networking. Can you explain me your words?

Comment: @ValentinaGenova, you are doing TCP/IP, you can't see packets in application level for TCP.

Comment: Yes, I know,but than how can I write code to see the packets on Level 4? or just to use ... wireshark?

Comment: @ValentinaGenova: Next time please ask your question more clearly.

Comment: This is very poor code and embodies several mistakes. It assumes the file size fits into an int; that the entire file fits into memory; and that read() fills the buffer. Then it wastes time reading the entire file into memory when it could be writing it out to the network a chunk at a time. Same happens at the other end. Downvote.

Comment: @EJP: Well, it's based on his code, so it's a modification and not my code. The question was how to modify it to make it work, not how to write your own.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My code isn't good, that's why I write my question here, to find the best advice in the area. I saw, that you help many people to fix their codes and mistakes.